# Google Lighthouse Metrics do not match speed index score

Tags: performance, performance-testing, google-developers-console, lighthouse, web-performance

I am currently testing the performance of my site with Google Lighthouse on Chrome Debugger.
I am getting several orange indicators despite their numbers falling into the green coding based on web.dev.

My result:
[Google Lighthouse result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrxjm.png)

1. I am getting **1.5s for speed index**, which lighthouse indicates [**0-3.4s should be Green**](https://web.dev/speed-index/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools).
2. I am getting **2.2s for Largest Contentful Paint**, which lighthouse indicates [**0-2.5s should be Green**](https://web.dev/lighthouse-largest-contentful-paint/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools).
3. I am getting **200ms for Total Blocking Time**, which lighthouse indicates [**0-200ms should be Green**](https://web.dev/lighthouse-total-blocking-time/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools).

My lighthouse version is 7.2.0 and this is the [runtime settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvQEV.png).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the grading for mobile times but running a desktop report.

You should always select "mobile" for the "Device" setting if you are trying to use those numbers.

I am quite surprised they do not say that within the docs, that is an oversight on their part.

Plug your values into the [Lighthouse Scoring Calculator](https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/scorecalc/#FCP=910&SI=1500&FMP=4000&TTI=1720&FCI=6500&LCP=2190&TBT=200&CLS=0.06&device=desktop&version=8) and select "Desktop", you can then adjust the sliders to see where your scores turn green if you want to check desktop performance.

Desktop testing is not really worth it as even bloated sites will score well, you should nearly always be running a mobile test as Google is mobile first in rankings and uses mobile scores for Web Vitals etc.